# php compact() function and laravel newbie question

Tags: php, laravel

For laravel when a collection is passed to the view. The compact function is sometimes used in the controller (as follows):

```
 public function index()
 {
     $projects = Project::all();
     return view ('projects.index',compact('projects'));
 }
```

but according to the php manual the compact function uses variables to create an array. Why does the function work when `Project::all()` is an array not variables.

In the manual it gives the following example:

```
<?php
$city  = "San Francisco";
$state = "CA";
$event = "SIGGRAPH";

$location_vars = array("city", "state");

$result = compact("event", "nothing_here", $location_vars);
print_r($result);
?>
```

> where the result is: Array (
>       [event] => SIGGRAPH
>       [city] => San Francisco
>       [state] => CA )

If return $projects gives:

```
id: 1
title:  "test"
description:    "test2"
created_at: "2019-03-02 19:18:50"
updated_at: "2019-03-02 19:18:50"
```

It's just the result from a database. It's already an array.

I would assume that compact(project) should give an error as per the manual.

Comment: It’s just shorthand for `['projects' => $projects]`. It doesn’t matter what `$projects` contains exactly.

Comment: yeah i know that but if you go into the manual it says: compact — Create array containing variables and their values. $projects is already an array. There's no variables in there. How is it working?

Comment: The manual gives an example with strings, but the values can also be arrays, or anything else. So the result is an array of arrays. `$projects` is the *variable*, its value is an array.

Comment: oh I see now....

Comment: Note it’s not `compact($project)`, it’s `compact('projects')`.

Comment: @deseze yeah I changed it to compact('projects'). Thanks